# In the Zchus (merit) of?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

Which specific Zchus did Miriam have for the well,Moshe for the מן Mann, and Ahron for the Ananie Hakovod (clouds of glory)?

Comment: Besides for setting up the answer, why do you assume that there was a specific zechus? When we talk about zechus avos, we don't refer to a specific action they did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Shach** on the Torah says the reason Miriam got the well was because she brought the Niddos(ritually unpure women) in Egypt to cleanse themselves in the Mikva (ritual path).The second answer brought by the **Rabbenu Bachyeh** is since she waited by the water to see what would happen to Moshe the Jews got the water of the well.

The reason Moshe's Zchus brought the מן was: since Moshe brought down the Torah, the spiritual food for the soul, it was in his merit we got the מן, the physical food for the body.

The reason Ahron's merit brought the *Ananie Hakovod* was, since he covered for the Jews by the sin of the Golden Calf saying it was the *Erev Rav* so to Hashem covered the Jews from the elements all the years in the Desert.

Comment: sources [15 char]?